# Align dropdown menu to center with 100% width of contianer

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this drop-down menu which I need to modify so that drop-down menu will 100% width of container and horizontally center aligned.

I have made some change to it but aligning it to center does not seem to be working. I tried a few things.

I want the menu to look like this when you hover over any parent menu:

[image]

```
.dropdown {
     margin-left: -250px;/*new*/
}
```

This made it work for second menu. If I have to achieve this for all menu items which have sub menu then I have to use jQuery to target it or nth type of css. But I want it to be dynamic, otherwise if I do it like this then there are chances menu design will break if we add one more parent menu or remove any parent menu.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksrkdkcp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contain all your menu in a wrapper that has the desired width of the "mega-menu". This container has to have `position:relative`. You also need to make sure no other ancestor between the actual mega-menus and the menu container has `position:relative`.

Here's a fixed version of [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ksrkdkcp/2/). I only took care of the positioning, not the rest of your CSS problems.

Relevant CSS:

```
nav {  
  position: relative;
  min-width: 640px;
}
nav>ul.nav, nav>ul.nav>li {
  position: static;
}
nav>ul.nav>li>.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

My personal opinion is you need to better understand positioning in CSS. Here's [a tutorial](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) that will get you up to speed fast on the subject.

Comment: I will try it on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript. This can be achieved purely by CSS:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; line-height: 1; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-decoration: none;}

nav ul {display: block; text-align: center; position: relative;}
nav ul li {display: inline-block;}
nav ul li a {display: block; padding: 5px; margin: 0;}
nav ul li .sub-menu {position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #ccf; display: none; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box;}
nav ul li:hover a {background-color: #ccf;}
nav ul li:hover a + .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item 1</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <h3>Item 1 Contents</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quae amet deserunt facilis facere modi animi iusto, qui error nulla mollitia excepturi quo laborum officiis eum autem, quidem aspernatur sed.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item 2</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <h3>Item 2 Contents</h3>
        <p>Impedit sit illo quod saepe eius, modi maiores explicabo pariatur, fuga veniam fugiat blanditiis perferendis vitae alias aliquid. Laborum debitis atque nemo fuga asperiores veritatis id tempora distinctio quasi doloribus!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item 3</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <h3>Item 3 Contents</h3>
        <p>Eos asperiores excepturi dolorem voluptas, quae tenetur. Rerum consequuntur, excepturi voluptas aliquid earum facilis, magnam totam blanditiis est, voluptate eaque dolorem a? Id incidunt, provident minus vitae consequatur dignissimos dolore!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Item 4</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <h3>Item 4 Contents</h3>
        <p>Sit ea quibusdam non, reiciendis quia blanditiis? Cupiditate laborum dicta ratione quisquam autem tempore molestiae nesciunt, magni fugiat, necessitatibus ea pariatur minus fugit at aspernatur quaerat laboriosam, natus quas minima.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```